# Feedback Form Exploitation possible or not?

Tags: php, exploit, html, email-spoofing, css

how an attacker can exploit the below provided feedback form in a company website containing the company’s domain? the feedback form does not store  data into a database. The server side code only mails the administrator. plz Do not include DOS attacks.

Code for the above form:

`<form action="serverUrl" method="POST">
Your name: <br>
<input type="text" name="realname"><br>
<br>
Your email: <br>
<input type="text" name="email"><br>
<br>
Your comments: <br>
<textarea name="comments" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`

Answer (score 7):

Posting a body such as this:

```
realname%3DSisodiya%20Chhatrapalsinh%26email%3D%60rm%20-rf%20%2F%60%26comments%3DDo%20your%20own%20homework%26submit%3DSubmit
```

Comment: But how exactly will it work? what will it do?

Comment: I s'pose it's really just as well that you did not include the "shellshock" string in the email address.